# converting code into classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, if-statement, vbscript

I want to convert the below string into **classic asp code** can any one help
email has some value but it is not going inside the Loop
Can any one help me.

```
If (IsEmpty(email) And IsNull(email)) Then

EndIf
```

Comment: You wrote email has a value, and is not going in. Isn't that what's supposed to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always try:

```
If IsEmpty(email) = True Then
    'uninitialized
ElseIf IsNull(email) = True Then
    'contains null value
ElseIf email = ""
    'contains zero length string
Else
    'Response.Write email
    'MsgBox email
End If
```

In most cases I try to code so that the variable is guaranteed to be initialized so you don't need to run the IsEmpty check.

```
Option Explicit

Dim email
email = ""
```

Answer (score 4):

The code looks like its VBScript already so there is no "conversion" needed, however the code is faulty.  Should be:

```
If IsEmpty(email) Or IsNull(email) Then

End If
```

a variable cannot both be empty *and* contain a Null at the same time hence the orginal conditional expression was always false.

Comment: Thanx for your reply, But still it is not going inside the if Condition.

Comment: Since the email is not empty, the condition is false.

Comment: @user11514:  If your expectation is that the condition be true when email is not empty or null then the condition should be `Not (IsEmpty(email) Or IsNull(email))`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check the length of the email variable:

```
 If Len(Trim(email)) > 0 Then

 Else

    YOUR CODE HERE

 End If
```

Comment: FYI, plain Trim function does both LTrim and RTrim at the same time. Also, your code will cause problems if the variable is uninitialized or null.

Comment: code updated, and i don't get errors when it's uninitialized or null.